# Populate Crystal Reports data at runtime without data source

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, datasource

Is there a way in generating a report in Crystal Reports without defining its data source. What I want to do is to use Crystal Reports just to come up with a layout and fill it up with data at run-time. By doing this, it will not be bound to anything, making it data source agnostic.

Comment: what do you mean by without source? You are asking to populate data then without source. if there is no source of data then how can it be populated? Do you mean by without creating connection with database in database explorer?

Comment: Yes. I mean, by without creating a database connection. I want the report to be unbounded from a data source and just populate it in a different module of my application.

Comment: I think you can't do that because reports are based on fields that have a specific type and Crystal Reports uses those types and some other field attributes ;).

Comment: @justelouise use a dataset (dataset.xsd) without creating connection with dbms.

Answer (score -1):

I think this solution can help you:

- You need to have a connection to a database (E.g. with ADO).
- Instead of selecting a table or view you can use SQL Query option
- For your query use below syntax (For SQL Server):

  ```
  SELECT CONVERT(0 AS bigint) As Id,
         CONVERT(0 AS varchar(20)) As FirstName,
         CONVERT(0 AS varchar(20)) AS LastName,
         CONVERT(0 AS bit) AS isActive,
         ....
  ```

  > Note this points:
  >
  > - Match type of your current `SELECT` statement with your run-time query.
  > - In run-time Crystal will ignore difference between names of fields and it will assign values to fields from left to right (Not based on names).

Comment: @downvoter: As a principle in SO, please explain your downvote! ;)